# DDD Одна Машина и разные модели

Tags: c#, домен, модель-данных, ddd

**Исходные условия:**
- У нас есть класс измерительного прибора (MeasureDevice). MeasureDevice является сущностью.
- Есть различные типы моделей измерительного прибора. Каждая модель также является сущностью. Модели измерительных приборов могут различаться между собой набором параметров.
- Есть приложение, в котором пользователь регистрирует измерительный прибор. При регистрации прибора указывается его модель. Мы помним, что модели могут отличаться между собой набором параметров.

**Ситуация:**
 Пользователь зарегистрировал измерительный прибор и некоторое время спустя понял, что ошибся с типом модели. Пользователь хочет поменять модель прибора на другую, в которой предусмотрен несколько иной набор параметров.

**Вопрос:**
Как можно разрешить представленную ситуацию?

**P. S.** Если модели различаются между собой набором параметров, то, по идее, каждая из них представляет собой отдельный класс-сущность со своим набором свойств, правил валидации и т. д. Однако как быть с типом модели, которая должна храниться в классе MeasureDevice? Типы модели ведь могут быть разные.

Есть вариант хранить MeasureDeviceID, в котором представлена пара (ID, modelType). При этом modelType является перечислением (enum). Однако в таком случае необходимо будет постоянно корректировать enum. В целом такой подход вызывает у меня сильные сомнения.

Comment: Мое мнение - в простом варианте пользователь создает новый девайс с нужным типом, старый удаляет или ссылается из него на новый. Из сложных вариантов - он "меняет" тип и дозаполняет "новые" свойства. Второе реализовывать не так то приятно, но в целом на кейс "я ошибся, как поправить?" второй вариант смотрится лучше. И да, в рамках ДДД смена типа конечно не очень смотрится, но прямо таки противоречия я не вижу.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но как лучше реализовать такую замену типа?

Comment: Смотрите в сторону паттернов: Abstract Factory, Builder, Adapter. Вот источник https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/ почитайте возможно найдет для себя подходящий

Answer (score 2):

Заявляем, что `MeasureDevice` может менять тип в рамках собственных наследников.
Условно, сущность умеет в `ConvertTo<T>()` или фабрика умеет в  `ConvertFrom<T>\CreateFrom<T>()`.

А дальше долго и уныло описываем все потенциальные конвертации. Например, если приборА был переделан в приборБ, то его собственное свойствоА должно быть присвоено(возможно с какими то изменениями) в свойствоБ прибораБ. Тут сильно помогают абстракции, т.е. изменения между двумя соседними приборами, у которых отличие в одном свойстве могут быть не описаны совсем, потому как нечего перетаскивать, а изменение из абсолютно несовместимых приборов - либо запрещены, либо будут равноценны фактически созданию новой сущности просто под старым идентификатором.

Что-то вида:

```
  if (source is entityA))
    Map(source.Properties.PropertyA, target.Properties.PropertyB);
```

---

Да, я сознательно не описываю жизнь системы с такими изменениями. Есть большая веротность, что где то была ссылка на приборА и после конвертации ссылка стала неподходящей в терминах предметной области, т.к. приборБ там никто не ждёт. Что с этим делать - нужно решать по конкретным кейсам, хороших советов нет.

---

Надо понимать, что не нужен универсальный механизм преобразования всего во всё. Обычно прикладные кейсы действительно простые, когда что-то очень похожее и их довольно просто друг в друга перегонять.

Comment: Большое спасибо за развернутый ответ. Может быть я не так Вас понял, просто в самой программе должна быть возможность изменения самой модели на другой тип. ПриборА так и остается тем же прибором. Новая сущность не создается. Я видел другие подходы к данному вопросу, но там все строилось вокруг базы данных с операциями над DataRow. Но там был только CRUD, а доменной модели не было вообще, т. е. я не увидел вообще классов, описывающих конкретный прибор. Все было на уровне строк из базы. Может так и было проще, но понимать такой код значительно труднее, да и документировать трудно.

Comment: @Eladei перечитал ещё раз вопрос. Если у вас элементарное прибор-модель, то в чём проблема смены одной модели на другую то? Если вы делали всё по ДДД и обе из них получились сущностями, то они не должны практически друг от друга зависеть.

Comment: Дело в том, что для одного и того же прибора может быть в данном случае несколько классов-сущностей моделей. Именно классов. У каждого класса модели разный набор свойств. Пользователь может ошибиться именно типом модели. Допустим ему понадобиться поменять модель на модель другого типа с другим наборов свойств. Именно с другим набором, не другими значениями. Как тогда осуществлять связь сущности прибора с моделью, если существует несколько классов моделей для конкретного прибора? Причем для каждого класса модели определен свой класс объекта-значения ID, например ModelOneID.

Comment: Monk, исходя из всех Ваших рекомендаций, я пришел к выводу, что лучше сохранять связки типа СущностьПриборА - МодельПрибораА, СущностьПриборБ - МодельПрибораБ. При смене модели прибора в программе следовать следующему сценарию: 1) Была МодельПрибораА; 2) Выбрана МодельПрибораБ; 3) Создать СущностьПриборБ; 4) Удалить СущностьПриборА. При этом в самой программе у пользователя будет складываться ощущение, что он работает с одним и тем же прибором, а меняется только его модель.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте базовый тип ModelBase и наследуйте от него все модели, ссылку на ModelBase храните в MeasureDevice.

Comment: Только как в таком случае обращаться к свойствам, определенным в каждой отдельной модели? Частные свойства каждого конкретного типа будут недоступны. Использование typeof смахивает на сode smell.